# By getting a combo card and using its given SSN, will I lose my previous status?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard, application-status

If someone with F-2 visa status who is inside the US, files I-485, I-765 and I-131 forms (after her spouse filed I-140) to get EAD/AP card also Social Security Number, if she uses only obtained SSN to apply for a credit card, will she lose her F-2 status?

Does using SSN for something like getting a credit card mean EAD/AP combo card usage and losing the previous status?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much "usage" of something that affects the status, but doing something that is not allowed on that status violates the status. Since working is not allowed on F2, working (even if working legally because you have an EAD) violates the F2 status. However, "using" the EAD or the SSN for purposes other than working like getting a driver's license or bank account, doesn't violate F2 status because those things are not disallowed on F2 status.

Comment: I just want to get a credit card because many banks need SSN to give you a credit card.